# textContent and innerHtml don't work inside function

Tags: javascript

I want to simply change text of a paragraph inside function but it doesn't work in my case.

Although when I log this, it shows the element with changed value inside but "old" value as it's textContent.

The problem concerns last function called drawCard.

Here is a **[preview](https://isaayy.github.io/JavaScript-projects/blackjack/index.html)** hosted on github pages and code:

```
'use strict';

let money = 500;
let playerBet = 0 ;
let playerScore = 0;
let dealerScore = 0;

// #######################################
// #######################################
// BET

// Bet amount 
const addBetAmount = document.querySelectorAll('.bet-amount');
const sumBetAmountBox = document.querySelector('.player-bet');
const placeBet = document.querySelector('.bet-btn');
const betBox = document.querySelector('.bet');
const customBet = document.querySelector('.custom-bet-amount');

for (const betAmount of addBetAmount){
    betAmount.addEventListener('click',() => {
        if(playerBet<money){
            if(betAmount.textContent === "All in")
                playerBet = money;
            else{
                if (playerBet + Number(betAmount.textContent) > money)
                    playerBet = money;
                else 
                    playerBet += Number(betAmount.textContent);
            }
            sumBetAmountBox.textContent = playerBet;
        }
    })
}

// Place bet
const menuFront = document.querySelector('.menu__side--front');
const menuBack = document.querySelector('.menu__side--back');
const placedBetBox = document.querySelector('.placed-bet');


placeBet.addEventListener('click',() =>{
    if (playerBet){
        betBox.textContent = playerBet;
        placedBetBox.classList.toggle('hidden');
        let audio = new Audio('img/drop.mp3');
        audio.play();

        playerBet = 0;
        sumBetAmountBox.textContent = playerBet;
        
        // draw cards
        drawCard('player',playerScore);
        // drawCard('dealer',dealerScore);
        // drawCard('player',playerScore);
        setTimeout(drawCard.bind(null,'dealer',dealerScore),2000);
        setTimeout(drawCard.bind(null,'player',playerScore),2000);

        // switch menu
        menuFront.classList.add('swipe-front');
        menuBack.classList.add('swipe-back');
    }
    else alert('In order to play you have to place a bet')
    
})

// Custom bet value
customBet.addEventListener('blur',() => {
    if (customBet.value > 0){
        if (customBet.value > money)
            playerBet = money;
        else
            playerBet = customBet.value;
        sumBetAmountBox.textContent = playerBet;
    }
    else alert('Bet must be greater than 0')
})

// Clear bet
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear');

clearBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playerBet = 0 ;
    sumBetAmountBox.textContent = playerBet;
    customBet.value = ''
})


// #######################################
// #######################################
// Draw cards

const playerCardsBox = document.querySelector('.player-cards');
const dealerCardsBox = document.querySelector('.dealer-cards');

let playerScoreBox = document.querySelector('.player-score');
let dealerScoreBox = document.querySelector('.dealer-score');

const drawCard = (currentPlayer,score) => {
    const values = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'J','Q','K','A'];
    const suits = ['C','D','H','S'];

    const randomValuesIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);
    const randomSuitsIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * suits.length);

    const drawnValue = values[randomValuesIndex];
    const drawnSuit = suits[randomSuitsIndex];

    if (typeof drawnValue == 'number'){
        score += drawnValue;
    }

    else {
        // TODO exception 
        score += 10;
    }
    if (currentPlayer == 'player'){
        playerCardsBox.innerHTML += `<img src="img/${drawnValue+drawnSuit}.png" alt="card" class="card slide-in">`
        playerScoreBox.innerHTML = "15"; // -> doesn't update text !!!!!
        playerScore = score;
       
    }
        
    else{
        console.log(dealerScoreBox,dealerScoreBox.textContent);
        dealerCardsBox.innerHTML += `<img src="img/${drawnValue+drawnSuit}.png" alt="card">`
        dealerScoreBox.textContent = "5"; // -> doesn't update text !!!!!
        dealerScore = score;
    }
    console.log(dealerScoreBox,dealerScoreBox.textContent); // -> result:  element, "5" !!!!!
} 
playerScoreBox.innerHTML = "77"; // -> works fine !!!!
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blackjack</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="dealer-cards">
            <p class="score dealer-score"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="player-cards">
                <div class="placed-bet hidden">
                    <img src="img/chip.png" alt="poker chip">
                    <p class="bet">1230$</p>
                </div>
                <p class="score player-score">11</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu__side  menu__side--front">
            <p class="menu__balance-p">Balance: <span class="balance">500$</span></p>
            <p class="menu__bet-p">Bet:</p>
            <div class="menu__bet-amount">
                <input type="number" class="custom-bet-amount" >
                <a class="bet-amount">100</a>
                <a class="bet-amount">250</a>
                <a class="bet-amount">500</a>
                <a class="bet-amount">1000</a>
                <a class="bet-amount">All in</a>
                <a class="clear">Clear</a>
                <p>Your bet: <span class="player-bet">0$</span></p>
                <button class="btn bet-btn">Bet</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu__side menu__side--back">
            <button class="hit btn btn--big">Hit</button>
            <button class="stand btn btn--big">Stand</button>
            <button class="double btn btn--big">Double</button>
            <button class="split btn btn--big">Split</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;500;600&display=swap");
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  padding: 5rem;
  background-color: #121417;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0  0;
  width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 900px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.main .dealer-cards,
.main .player-cards {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid white;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
      align-self: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.main .dealer-cards > img,
.main .player-cards > img {
  width: 7rem;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.main .dealer-cards > img:not(:first-child),
.main .player-cards > img:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: .5rem;
}

.main .dealer-cards::before,
.main .player-cards::before {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  bottom: 102%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.main .dealer-cards .score,
.main .player-cards .score {
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 85%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.main .dealer-cards::before {
  content: 'Dealer';
}

.main .player-cards::before {
  content: 'You';
}

.main .player-cards .placed-bet {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  top: 100%;
  left: 80%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.main .player-cards .placed-bet img {
  width: 3rem;
}

.main .player-cards .placed-bet p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F6F7F8;
  margin-left: .5rem;
}

.menu {
  border: 2px solid #121417;
  width: 1440px;
  height: 7rem;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0  0 7px 7px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu__side {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.menu__side--back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
          transform: rotateX(180deg);
  background-color: white;
}

.menu__balance-p {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.menu__balance-p span {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.menu__bet-amount {
  margin-left: .5rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.menu__bet-amount input {
  width: 3rem;
  padding: .2rem;
}

.menu__bet-amount a {
  background-color: #fdbfcd;
  padding: .2rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu__bet-amount p {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

.menu__bet-amount p span {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.menu .btn {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding: .3rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: #FF3366;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .btn--big {
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu .btn--big:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
          transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.menu .btn--big:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
          transform: translateY(0);
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.swipe-front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
          transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

.swipe-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
          transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

Comment: Is all this code (including extensive CSS) really needed to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the Moment you call

```
playerCardsBox.innerHTML +=
```

the element get recreated, therefore the variable playerScoreBox points to an element that does not exist anymore.
You could try to research it with

```
document.querySelector('.player-score').innerHTML = "15";
```

Comment: thanks it works now as I wanted, but still idk why it won't work with variable a little bit weird

Comment: @fluffy If you change the html directy by modifying the string, javascript cannot keep track of the changes and parses the whole node again. The <p> gets recreated and the variable points to a <p> that does not exist anymore.